# What's the best way to load a batch node from a texture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to reference a texture directly in the creation of a batch node:

`CCSpriteBatchNode*batch=[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithTexture:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"anyFrame.png"].texture];`

Is this the only way to do it? Seems a bit... long. Having to pick out a random sprite in your texture, then use it's texture; the goal is to get the entire texture atlas in the batch node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"MyTexture.png"]
```

Comment: trying to use a texture already loaded, so it doesn't have to load ig again

Comment: It won't try to load it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the texture file name (used as key in the cache), I assume you have tried CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile(textureFilename)?

As far as i understand it, this would reuse the texture in cache memory if already loaded, or load it from disk otherwise.

Comment: ah, so the simple `batchNodeWithFile` method simply uses what is already in memory, and won't try to load it again?